# Yii2 Reading PUT request body after oauth2 server already did it

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, yii2, http-put

I am working on REST API with oauth2 authorization.
For Oauth2 server i use https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php

Php doc says here http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

*Prior to PHP 5.6, a stream opened with php://input could only be read once; the stream did not support seek operations. However, depending on the SAPI implementation, it may be possible to open another php://input stream and restart reading. This is only possible if the request body data has been saved. Typically, this is the case for POST requests, but not other request methods, such as PUT or PROPFIND.*

In short it means that it is possible to read POST body twice, but not PUT.

But Oauth2 server reads it first time here https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/blob/develop/src/OAuth2/Request.php#L114

So when i read raw body in Yii2 Request, it is empty. (only on PUT, on POST and PATCH it is ok and can be read twice).
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Request.php#L345

I know that this is kind of expected, no bugs. But what would be the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you create that auth server, run this (depending in where you do authentication, you can use `beforeAction()`, or even `init()`:

```
$content = Yii::$app->request->rawBody;
$authentication = Request::createFromGlobals();
if ($content)
   $authentication->content = $content;
```

Now, I don't know how/where you use the component, so it might not fully work, but in theory it should.

Comment: Thank you, i did it this way, but to be honest it doesn't look good to me.
I am going to have oauth server not to read body and allow authorization only in header.
I wonder why it reads body at all even if i set to false `allow_credentials_in_request_body` parameter.

Comment: Agreed. But I can't come up with a better solution right now. Let me know if you do.

Comment: Sure, i will dig into the server to understand how it works.